# update many times from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this query it only gets the last media and delete it from table1

```
UPDATE table1
        join
    table2 as b ON table1.tree_points_guid = b.tree_points_guid
        left outer join
    table3 as m ON table1.media_guid like concat('%', m.media_guid, '%') 
set 
    table1.media_guid = REPLACE(table1.media_guid,
        concat(m.media_guid, '_', media_type_guid),
        '')
where
    m.media_setting_guid = '3be0eead659d'
        and m.user_guid <> b.user_guid
        and table1.media_guid like concat('%', m.media_guid, '%')
;
```

I have

```
tree_point_media  media_guid 
1                     1|2|3
```

I want after update

```
tree_point_media  media_guid 
1                     null
```

But my query do only

```
tree_point_media  media_guid 
1                    1|2|
```

after three click on the same query I can have my desired result
but I want to do this with only one execute

Comment: Problems like this are why you shouldn't put lists into a single column. You should normalize your data.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry,can't understand

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @Barmar I can't change in design of table by any way , isn't another solution

Comment: Then I think you'll need to write a stored procedure that updates the field in a loop.

Comment: I already do it but it too slow

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL documentation is quite clear about what happens when there are multiple matches in a `join`:

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named
>   in table_references that satisfy the conditions. Each matching row is
>   **updated once**, even if it matches the conditions multiple times. For
>   multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

That is, one of the arbitrary matching rows is used for the update.

The real solution in your case -- as suggested by Barmar in a comment -- is to have a proper junction table with one row per `tree_point_media` and `media_guid`.  In that case, the "update" would be easy, a simple `delete` statement. Storing lists of things in a string is a bad idea.  Storing lists of numerical ids is doubly bad, because you are storing integers as strings.  SQL has this great data structure for storing lists; it is called a table.

If you cannot create a junction table, for some reason, your options are rather limited.  The simplest solution in that case is to write a stored procedure that repeatedly does the update in a loop until no records match.

Comment: thanks , but I already do this with loop statement , but the problem that stored proc is too slow

Comment: @Nesreenadly . . . Then fix your data structure and use a junction table.